# Linux error: Network error: connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh

I have facing a Network Error: Connection refused when I try to SSH using PUtty to my Oracle Linux Server. What happens is that when I reboot the server I will be able to SSH to the Linux box but after about 4 hours and the connection is idle when I try to SSH again to the Oracle Linux Box I get Network error: Connection refused.

I have even added the port 22 to be allowed access permanently from the Oracle Linux firewall. Note that I can only SSH into the Linux Box after restarting but this access is not permanent, because if the SSH session becomes idle from about 3hours, I then get the error I have mentioned if I try to SSH.

Comment: Do you have any other means of checking your connection between the two machines? What does the log on the Oracle box say?

Comment: Hi, Its not an Oracle Virtual Box, if i get you right, the OS is Oracle Linux 7.5 or Rather Redhat 7. In terms of logs i am not sure which ones do u mean?

Comment: Guys may anyone help me, i am stuck here.

Comment: Well.. Isn't it kind of obvious to check the ssh logs if you are having problems connecting over ssh? try journalctl _COMM=sshd , also check system log. Nobody will help you when you do no research, but ask anyway.

Comment: Hi Anders, the journalctl command is giving me the folloing response:

Comment: Hi Anders, the journalctl command is giving me the following response:                 [root@VasOracleDB ssh]# journalctl _COMM=sshd
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-09-11 12:53:42 CAT, end at Wed 2018-09-12 08:00:02 CAT. --
Sep 11 13:23:37 VasOracleDB sshd[12528]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 11 13:23:37 VasOracleDB sshd[12528]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 11 13:23:43 VasOracleDB sshd[12528]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Sep 11 13:23:43 VasOracleDB sshd[12553]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 11 13:23:43 VasOracleDB sshd[12553]: Server listening on :: port 22

Comment: Well, its not possible to debug this in the comments. And what parts of the log did you leave out? Use a site like pastebin for stuff like this. Use google, nobody will answer a question when you haven't done any research yourself. If you don't want to research your own problem so people actually have any useful information to start helping you, you have to pay $$ and hire someone.

Comment: When the ssh connection gets refused, i cant also access the Oracle EM Express Page via https://10.10.4.74:5500/em . These ports get actively refused, but in the firewall all these ports have been added permanently. I can also ping 10.10.4.74 linux box even though i cannot connect via ssh. The server will not have gone on standby. If restart the server i can access the server via putty ssh or even access any web resource on the server, but after about 4hours plus when the server is idle, these connections behave like they have been closed yet they are open and i cant access them anymore.

Comment: The only advice I can give you, is to check logs as soon as you are unable to login anymore. Firewall, system log, ssh. Try restarting sshd instead of whole server etc. debugging is a skill you need to learn. Meaning that you have to be willing to spend countless hours on forums, stack exchange, search engines and documentation. Nobody can help if you don't even show logs for relevant stuff. Debugging a problem can be hard enough when you are at the computer and have access to *everything*. A lot of people seem to think people on Stack Exchange are Wizards :laugh: